# state is not updating through useState

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add google sign in function to my website. I'd like to update username state in googleOnSuccess function when google api sends back its response but the state is not updating. I'm using 'react-google-login' package for the sign in process. The updateToken() function from navbar component is there to render navbar again with an username when a user is logged in.

LoginModal.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../../App.scss";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody } from "reactstrap";
import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login";

const LoginModal = ({ updateToken }) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("/login", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem("userToken", data.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem("username", data.username);
        updateToken();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const googleOnSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    const userEmail = res.profileObj.email;
    setUsername(userEmail.substring(0, userEmail.indexOf("@")));

    // console.log(`Username: ${username}`);
    localStorage.setItem("userToken", res.tokenObj.access_token);
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    updateToken();
    alert("Logged In Successfully");
  };

  const googleOnFailure = (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    alert("Log In Failed");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button className="nav-button login-button" color="link" onClick={toggle}>
        LOG IN
      </Button>

      <Modal className="auth-modal" isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalHeader className="modal-header" toggle={toggle}>
          Log in
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody className="modal-body">
          <GoogleLogin
            clientId="1087910724182-02v9tf6jm6h867i3vd81rui2dm4b6jvb.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            render={(renderProps) => (
              <Button
                onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                color="link"
                className="google-button"
              >
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
                CONTINUE WITH GOOGLE
              </Button>
            )}
            onSuccess={googleOnSuccess}
            onFailure={googleOnFailure}
            cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
          />
          <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="input-buttons-wrapper">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="USERNAME"
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="PASSWORD"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              className="modal-login-button"
              color="primary"
              onClick={toggle}
            >
              LOG IN
            </Button>
          </form>
          <p className="go-to-signup">New to FakeReddit? SIGN UP </p>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginModal;
```

Comment: state is updated asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setting state is async there is no guarantee it will be set by the time you try to use it here

```
localStorage.setItem("username", username);
```

when you want to do something like this within the same function which you set state, it is best to use the same value that you set the state with. In this case it seems to be

```
userEmail.substring(0, userEmail.indexOf("@"))
```

Use that value for your localStorage.setItem line instead of using the state object directly since it probably hasn't updated yet.